# How do I setup a local Django development environment on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, django, apache, ubuntu

Finally made the switch from Windows to Linux (Ubuntu). I am teaching myself Python + Django.

GOAL: I want to setup a local development environment where I can build a django application and run it locally before deploying it live online.

SO FAR: Python comes installed with Linux. Gedit does also. Ok great. After that I am lost.

I am not sure how to proceed. I am a total Linux noob. I am guessing I need apache running, mysql running, and django to run. I don't know how to setup these things to run or how to set the proper directories or what I need to link to what... really I am not even sure what the right questions are to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick answer:

Just install django via their documentation, and you will not even need apache running as it will run its own server. You can use sqlite as a db and you won't even have to worry about mysql. This is if your goal is to learn django and get things running asap.

Otherwise, if you want to take the full route, you'll need to start learning a lot more (which isn't a bad thing). I'd say take a look at some of the slicehost guides for setting up apache, mysql in ubuntu:

http://articles.slicehost.com/2010/5/19/installing-apache-on-ubuntu

http://articles.slicehost.com/2011/3/10/installing-mysql-server-on-ubuntu

And then pick up with just installing django and going from there. The django tutorial is awesome. There's plenty of other documentation out there on the web & tutorials for setting up dev environments.

Comment: When you're ready to install Apache, I suggest you read this guide: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modwsgi/

Comment: Ok, so I just confirmed in my terminal window that I already have Django installed.

>>> import django
>>> print django.get_version()
1.3.1

Comment: @Dominik that linke appears to no longer be valid. Current link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have python

You can install pip:

```
easy_install pip
```

From now you can use pip to install your python libraries for example to install django

```
pip install django
```

For development I would prefer [pydev](http://pydev.org/), it has a support for django with the power of eclipse.